# How to enforce choices grouping in selectizeInput?

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I want to have grouped choices in selectizeInput. This can be done by providing a named list as the argument "choices".
However, if a group contains just 1 element, the "grouped display" of the choices doesn't work.
I think it interferes with the option to provide named vectors for single arguments. How can I achieve it, that the options are always grouped, even if there happens to be just 1 element in a group?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(uiOutput("type")),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$type <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(inputId = "color",
                     label = "Color",
                     choices = list(one = c(3,5,2,5,6),
                                    two = c("no", "yes", "no"),
                                    three = "only_option"),
                     multiple = T)
    })
  }
)
```

In the above case, the element "only_option" is wrongly assigned to the group "two".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to provide the single option as a list:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(uiOutput("type")),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$type <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "color",
        label = "Color",
        choices = list(
          one = list(3, 5, 2, 5, 6),
          two = list("no", "yes", "no"),
          three = list("only_option")
        ),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    })
  }
)
```

---

[image]